# Use variable as source array in map

Tags: jquery, arrays

My goal is to have a user click on a date and a map of the US changes to use a new array of data based off the year selected.

```
// When user clicks on li under years
  $('#years').children('li').click(function(){

    // Get last two characters of id and prepend y
    let id = 'y' + this.id.slice(-2);

    // Output is y04
    console.log(id);

    // Use id variable to get array for that year, then pass through getColour function.
    let newArray = $.map(id, function(item) { 
        return getColour("#e67d73", "#57bb8a", 16, 100, item) 
    });

    // step through states array and apply the colour value from newArray to each state
    states.forEach((state, index) => {
      const colour = newArray[index];
      $(state).css('fill', colour);
    });
  });
```

For the inital map load I am using. This works fine:

```
//Use y04 array for getColour function
let initialArray = y04.map(function(item) {
    return getColour("#e67d73", "#57bb8a", 16, 100, item)
});
```

I've done various testing with using `let newArray = id.map(//more code)` but from my research the `id` variable needs to be an object and not a string.

How can I convert my `id` string into an object that `.map` can use? Is it even possible pass a variable as the source array to a `.map`?

Comment: how `id` looks like?

Comment: What are the expected values for the `item` parameter for your `getColour` function?

Comment: @NinaScholz Do you mean the id variable or the elements id? The variable will be `y04` the actual elements id "2004" - "2019" as there are 15 options.

Comment: @MaazSyedAdeeb That is a number between 0 - 100. Provided by the array which looks like this `["31", "56",]`. It is used to randomise the colour as it's a heatmap of sorts.

Comment: `id.map(//more code)` what is the content of `id`? please add the values of the dynamic part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you have an array for each year then to use the value as a variable, you need to change your approach. You need to create a object data structure where each property will represent the value that you will get which will be associated with the array. Something like below:

```
// created a mapper data structure
var mapper = {
  y01: [1, 2, 3], // array y01 will be here
  y02: [1, 2, 3], // array y02 will be here
  y03: [1, 2, 3], // array y03 will be here
  y04: [1, 2, 3], // array y04 will be here
  .
  .
  .
};

// when you do the initial call
//Use y04 array for getColour function
let initialArray = mapper['y04'].map(function(item) {
  return getColour("#e67d73", "#57bb8a", 16, 100, item)
});


//inside the code
// When user clicks on li under years
$('#years').children('li').click(function() {

  // Get last two characters of id and prepend y
  let id = 'y' + this.id.slice(-2);

  // Output is y04
  console.log(id);

  // Use mapper to get the array using the id value
  let newArray = $.map(mapper[id], function(item) {
    return getColour("#e67d73", "#57bb8a", 16, 100, item)
  });

  // step through states array and apply the colour value from newArray to each state
  states.forEach((state, index) => {
    const colour = newArray[index];
    $(state).css('fill', colour);
  });
});
```

Comment: Test and it's working. I'm still pretty new to jQuery and wasn't aware of creating a data structure of arrays and accessing them like that.

Comment: @JoshRatcliffe programming is all about logic followed by proper data structure